# How can I access my XAMPP vhosts from a test browsers running inside Virtual Box?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, apache-http-server, xampp, virtual-host

Currently I'm doing development using XAMPP on OSX Snow Leopard. For Windows IE testing I want to use Virtual Box. How can I configure Virtual Box to let me access my local machine and various Apache vhosts?

I run my XAMPP test sites on port 8888. Hopefully this does not make things more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be

use **bridged** networking on the vbox

edit your xp hosts file : `windows/system32/drivers/hosts`

the file should be setup to point the domains of you vhosts  to your Apple Macs ip address.

eg:

```
192.168.0.2 vdomain.co.uk
```

Then you can point your xp machines web browser to vdomain.co.uk:8080/ and browse as normal